# Creating a new linux partition to the left of linux partition

Tags: partitioning, gparted, ext4

When I moved from windows to Linux I thought I may not use it much so I only used some 60gb for Linux. But nowadays I don't touch  windows. I would like to move the free space from windows partition to Linux. I am adding an image of my partition .

[image]

I would like to add the unallocated space to linux. When i try , I get an error saying I can only have 4 primary partitions. Is there anyway I can make this an ext4 . I would prefer to not move the existing linux system partition.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can add the unallocated space to your sda5 or sda7 partition. But you need to extend sda4 first.

Comment: Or you can extend sda4 to the left and then create another logical partition inside it.

Comment: sd5 is the root partition of linux. will extending sda4 , require me to move the root partition to left ?

Comment: Extending sda4 will not require to move sda5. But you can do it too, if you want. But after that you will probably need to re-install grub.

Answer (score 1):

You should move your Linux partition with the help of LiveUSB boot up or one of Windows partitioning tools. While you are actively using Linux, I don't think you can move the partition safely.

That is if you want to add the unallocated space to Linux partition of course.

Comment: I can move the partition from windows. But how risky is it ? Is there any chance of things going wrong?

Comment: I did the same a few weeks ago without any issue. Depends on the safety of the partitioning tool you use, but I don't think you should have any problems.